# when i try to install react-to-pdf package using this command : npm install react-to-pdf i get this errors

Tags: npm, installation, react-to-pdf

when i try to install react-to-pdf by using cmd : `npm i react-to-pdf`

i found

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: tenth-assignment-chef-recipe-hunter@0.0.0
npm ERR! Found: react@18.2.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"^18.2.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^16.5.2" from react-to-pdf@0.0.14
npm ERR! node_modules/react-to-pdf
npm ERR!   react-to-pdf@"0.0.14" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-05-05T06_34_02_033Z-debug-0.log
```

what is the problem there?

i tried to apply different cmd like `npm i react-to-pdf@latest`

Comment: Can you please provide node and react version